# Easiest way to treat number as numeric in perl?

Tags: perl

I have a condition:

```
next if ( ! ($x or $y or $z) );
```

The logic of the check is that at least one must be numerically non-zero to continue in the loop.

I trust that they actually are numbers.

The problem is that perl stores floats as strings internally. So a check on `! $x` where `$x='0.00'` does not actually evaluate to true: `my $x = 0.00;` `if ( ! $x ) { never_gets_here(); }`

What is the easiest way to force numeric evaluation of a variable without making the line too verbose?

Comment: convert it in the comparison: `next if(0+$x or 0+$y or 0+$z)`  BTW: `my $x = 0.00; if ( ! $x ) { print $x }`  does work as expected.

Comment: "perl stores floats as strings internally." is not true.

Comment: @ikegami: what he meant was probably  `my $x = '0.00'; if ( ! $x ) { print $x }`.  This would *not* work in a way a newbie could expect.

Comment: @rubber boots, Of course it wouldn't. But that doesn't demonstrate that Perl stores floats as strings. That's an example of a *user* storing a *decimal number* as a string. Perl stores decimal numbers in double-precision floats (or larger).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure where you get the idea that Perl stores floats as strings. Floats and strings are different things:

```
perl -le 'print 1 if 0.00'
perl -le 'print 2 if "0.00"'
2
```

If you want to force numeric context on an unknown scalar, you can just add zero to it, e.g.

```
unless ( $x + 0 ) { ... }
```

Comment: re floats vs strings, what am I see when I do this `perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; use Data::Dumper; my $x = 0; print Dumper($x), "\n";'` vs `perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; use Data::Dumper; my $x = 0.00; print Dumper($x), "\n";'` ? Thanks

Comment: @Dale Forester - for a more insightful look at Perl's internals, try `perl -e 'use Devel::Peek;Dump($_) for (0, 0.0, "0")'`

Comment: @Dale, Data::Dumper isn't very smart when it comes to serializing Perl data types. It will treat every scalar as a string, because you have to peek at Perl internals to discern the "real" type, which can and will change itself, and which can even be two things at the same time! (This is why you should not rely on having real type information in Perl.)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to check whether a number is numerically non-zero, there is an operator for that:

```
next if (! ($x != 0 or $y != 0 or $z != 0) )

    $x       bool $x      $x != 0
 --------   --------    ----------------------------
    0        false       false
  '0.00'     true        false
  '0E0'      true        false
  'string'   true        false, generates 'non-numeric' warning
    ''       false       false, generates 'non-numeric' warning
   undef     false       false, generates 'non-numeric' warning
```

Comment: alternately, `next if $x==0 and $y==0 and $z==0`

Answer (score 4):

To check if number has non-zero value you can just add 0:

```
$ perl -e "print '0.02' + 0;"
0.02
```

and

```
$ perl -e "print '0.00' + 0;"
0
```

which is falsy value in Perl:

```
$ perl -e "print (('0.00' + 0) ? 'true' : 'false');"
false
```

Answer (score 2):

Add zero (0) to the variable (just as you would in 'awk').

Answer (score 0):

You could use following shortcut if there are no ( or exclusively ) negative values, which is imho cleaner than adding zero to each single value:

```
next if ( $x + $y + $z == 0 );
```